# In fusion table LIMIT command is not working properly

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to query in fusion table as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE no=1 ORDER BY Date LIMIT 0, 10
```

the following command is working

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE no=1 ORDER BY Date LIMIT 10
```

why the first one is giving an error

Comment: The offset in Google Fusion is different. You'll have to add LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10. This is how the syntax should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT 0, 10`

doesn't look like a correct SQL syntax. It's usually `LIMIT <n>`, where n = number of rows.

see: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php